# Why signatures is null?

Tags: java, android, signatures

Good day!
I tried this code :

```
PackageInfo info = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(absolute_apk_name, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        if (info != null)
        {
            Signature[] sig = info.signatures;
            if (sig != null)
                sigstring = new String(sig[0].toChars());
        }
```

But `info.signatures == null`, and I do not have any idea "why?"
File in **absolute_apk_name** exists, I checked 
Android 2.1

**UPD:**

```
absolute_apk_name = "/data/data/ru.UseIT.SimpleFormsLauncher/files/SimpleFormsGeneral.apk"
```

apk was created with flags `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE|Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`

But if exec this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(absolute_apk_name )), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

It was installed.

Comment: @DrinkJavaCodeJava, I updete question

Comment: Try some other flags and see what happens.

Comment: @DrinkJavaCodeJava, what other flags? APPEND?

Comment: How about GET_PERMISSIONS. I know all files have permissions so try that.

Comment: @DrinkJavaCodeJava, can I see example? Just don't understand

Comment: @DrinkJavaCodeJava, and my code work in android 4*

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I don't understand why you're checking to see if the sig array is null.

Comment: What are the contents of your manifest? Do you have the right permissions (for your Android version)?

Comment: Is the APK signed, for any signatures to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the Android source, and it turns out that PackageManager#getPackageArchiveInfo(String, int) does not include signatures if Android version is 2.3.7 and less.

Please look below links.

http://tools.oesf.biz/android-2.3.7_r1.0/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#1891

http://tools.oesf.biz/android-4.0.3_r1.0/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#2121

Answer (score 1):

it is an android system bug see this 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9151#c8
this bug has fixed on 4.0+

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what your trying to achieve, but using the absolute apk name/path is incorrect, you need the packagename. I've been able to get the signatures using the following, just replace "com.android.chrome" with the package name of the app you want.

```
final PackageInfo pkgInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                    "com.android.chrome", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
final Signature[] signatures = pkgInfo.signatures;
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the signature of another apk, not installed

Comment: maybe use openssl to get the cert?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324120/how-to-view-the-identity-of-person-who-signed-the-apk-on-android-device

Comment: Wait are you doing this on the device? and trying to verify the signature of apk before installation?

Comment: Yes, before installation:)

Comment: looks like you're using the wrong Api then. PackageManager is for installed apps.

Comment: This is not true at all. As mentioned above early versions of android just wont return the signatures.